# Jekyll on github

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I rake new post on my local computer, and I pushed it to my github account successfully. Before I pushed it to github, I use `jekyll --server` to scan my modified files, it's successful.

But after I pushed it to github, the pages on github is different to my local server? I waited 10mins and I also cleared my browser cache, it still does not work.

Comment: run `jekyll build --safe` to see if your site builds correctly, and make sure you are [running the same version as github](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've committed the changes to your repository before pushing them to GitHub?

If you type in the terminal:

```
git status
```

You'll get a list of files that Git thinks have been modified, and it will tell you whether or not they've been added to the staging area.

Add each file to the staging area with:

```
git add <<filename goes here>>
```

Then commit them with:

```
git commit -m "<<commit message goes here>>"
```

Then finally push them to GitHub like this:

```
git push
```

They should then show up on GitHub pages.

Posting a link to your GitHub repository might also help us to diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what kind of page you are trying to put on Github. There are 2 different types of pages: user pages and project pages.

Documentation from Github is here https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages

If it's a project page, you need to push that into special branch called gh-pages. It won't work from master branch.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also want to consider that Github currently runs Jekyll version 1.5.1 which is rather out-of-date with the online Jekyll documentation which describes version 2.0.3.

So for example, Collections do not work as described.